# Как получить сведения о процессоре?

Tags: ассемблер

Здравствуйте! Как можно с помощью ассемблерных вставок получить сведения о процессоре?

**Дополнено.**

Вот нашел команду cpuid и код:

```
mov ЕАХ,О
cpuid ;EAX=0001h
mov mem, ЕВХ
mov mem+4, EDX
mov mem+8, ECX ;mem='Genuinelntel'
cpuid EAX=543h (например) ,EDX = lBFh
```

Но как это сделать вставкой на том же C?

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Comment: А какие именно сведения вас интересуют?

Comment: Просто "марка" процессора Intel или  AMD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Инструкция cpuid предназначена для получения информации о процессоре. Для некоторых компиляторов она доступна как расширение языка [__cpuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh(v=vs.100).aspx). [Пример использования](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#Accessing_the_id_from_other_languages)

```
int main()
{
    int a, b;

    for (a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
      __asm("cpuid":"=a"(b)           // EAX - в b (вывод)
      :      "a"(a)                   // a - в EAX (ввод)
      :      "%ebx", "%ecx", "%edx"); // cpuid всегда задействует их

        printf("Этот код %i дает %i\n", a, b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: спасибо вам огромное

Answer (score 0):

Если не получается сделать это inline-ассемблером в C, то попробуй написать на чистом ассемблере функции, возвращающие тебе нужную информацию, и собрать их в obj-файл. Этот obj файл подключи к компоновке, и в C можно будет использовать нужные функции, объявив их прототипы.

Comment: да здесь нет привязки именно к си, можно и на delphi (не в этом вопрос). я просто не понимаю, как можно реализовать данную задачу.
может быть так (на Delphi):
var b,d,c: string;

begin

asm

    mov eax,1

    cpuid

    mov b,ebx

    mov d,edx

    mov c,ecx
end

Comment: и потом уже проверять по это табличке http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cpuid#EAX

Comment: @Константин25, нехорошо, Дельфи использует некоторые регистры, в ассемблерной вставке, их нужно сохранять/восстанавливать:

> An asm statement must preserve the EDI, ESI, ESP, EBP, and EBX registers, but can freely modify the EAX, ECX, and EDX registers.

В частности в вашем коде cpuid перепишет ebx, а там хранится Self.

И, судя по вашему комментарию выше, вам нужен Vendor ID, для этого в eax занесите нуль. Здесь у вас единица - вы получаете Feature Information.

Comment: что то у меня ничего не выходит (

Comment: вы мне хоть скажите, вот то что я написал выше 

mov eax,1

cpuid

mov b,ebx

mov d,edx

mov c,ecx
хотя бы похоже на правду ?